# Java Swing using one of the table column as button

Tags: java, swing, jtable, jbutton

```
`
jTable1 = new javax.swing.JTable();

jTable1.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Segoe Script", 3, 14));

jTable1.setModel(new javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel(
    new Object [][] {
        {null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null},
        {null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null},
        {null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null},
        {null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null},
        {null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null},
        {null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null},
        {null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null},
        {null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null},
        {null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null},
        {null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null},
        {null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null},
        {null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null},
        {null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null},
        {null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null},
        {null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null},
        {null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null},
        {null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null},
        {null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null},
        {null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null},
        {null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null},
        {null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null},
        {null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null},
        {null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null},
        {null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null},
        {null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null},
        {null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null},
        {null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null},
        {null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null},
        {null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null},
        {null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null},
        {null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null},
        {null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null},
        {null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null},
        {null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null},
        {null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null},
        {null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null},
        {null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null},
        {null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null},
        {null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null},
        {null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null},
        {null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null},
        {null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null},
        {null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null},
        {null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null},
        {null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null},
        {null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null},
        {null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null},
        {null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null},
        {null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null},
        {null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null},
        {null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null},
        {null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null},
        {null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null},
        {null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null},
        {null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null},
        {null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null},
        {null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null},
        {null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null},
        {null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null},
        {null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null},
        {null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null},
        {null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null},
        {null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null},
        {null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null},
        {null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null},
        {null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null},
        {null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null},
        {null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null},
        {null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null},
        {null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null},
        {null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null},
        {null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null},
        {null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null},
        {null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null},
        {null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null},
        {null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null},
        {null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null},
        {null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null},
        {null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null},
        {null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null},
        {null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null},
        {null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null},
        {null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null},
        {null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null},
        {null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null},
        {null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null},
        {null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null},
        {null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null},
        {null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null},
        {null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null},
        {null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null},
        {null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null},
        {null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null},
        {null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null},
        {null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null},
        {null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null},
        {null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null},
        {null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null},
        {null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null},
        {null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null}
    },
    new String [] {
        "Id", "Name", "Sex", "Phone No.", "Address", "Membership", "Penalty", "Issue"
    }
) {
    Class[] types = new Class [] {
        java.lang.String.class, java.lang.String.class, java.lang.String.class, java.lang.Integer.class, java.lang.String.class, java.lang.String.class, java.lang.Boolean.class, java.lang.Boolean.class
    };

    public Class getColumnClass(int columnIndex) {
        return types [columnIndex];
    }
});
`
```

I want to use a name column as a button. I am using java swing in Net beans software.
How do I get it ? I read docs and even googled. But nothing is helping me out.
Can somebody help me to change all the cells of Name column to buttons?

Comment: search here, swing + jtable + jbutton

Comment: That huge array makes my feel dizzy.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look to oracle tutorials. These sections will help you

[Using renderers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#renderer)

[Using Other Editors](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#editor)

> You need to create a class that implements the TableCellEditor
>   interface. The AbstractCellEditor class is a good superclass to use.
>   It implements TableCellEditor's superinterface, CellEditor, saving you
>   the trouble of implementing the event firing code necessary for cell
>   editors.

Here you have related question with example and links [is it possible to include jbutton in jtable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/764417/is-it-possible-to-include-jbutton-in-a-jtable)

Here you have an example by @camickr a swing guru [table button column](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2009/07/12/table-button-column/)

Comment: please refer my code..and tell me what changes i need to make to set all cells under name column to set to buttons?

Comment: what have you tried so far with the information i gave you? there you have the links from oracle tutorials and a complete example with source code of what you need.

Comment: I changes java.lang.String to javax.Swing.Jbutton but its still given some errors.

Comment: you want the column name as a button? or all column cells?

Comment: Column cells as button

Comment: Ok then read the examples i gave you.. You need to create your own renderer and editor. You can use the one that camickr did you have the source code. Then you have to setup the renderer to the jtable as is specified in oracle tutorials.

Comment: @nachokk nice .... ignore this person +1

Comment: What's wrong with you ??